# php session not working in chrome and firefox but works in IE

Tags: php, session

i know this is a well asked question, but the solution provided doesn't clarify my query... :(
php sessions aren't working as expected... for first few tries, the session doesn't get logged.. but after fourth or fifth try, the session is getting logged.. not sure why this doesn't work at first instant... 
works with IE but not with fireforx and chrome..

### code:

in every page...

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
```

in session page...

```
<?php
  session_start();
   .
   .
   .
  $_SESSION['name']=$row['name'];
  $_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];
  session_write_close();
 }
```

thanks in advance... please respond! :)

Comment: did you get some error message or anything, please share that

Comment: The php session is not working but the problem is not in this code

Comment: If you echo the $_SESSION['name'] and id you get the right values?

Comment: did you try to clear the cache? it might be a cache problem

Comment: $session variables are not set at all.. when i check with isset function, the else part gets executed :(

Comment: @LabibIsmaiel.. cleared cache and also tried deleting the files of \tmp folder (as shown in phpinfo).... nothing works...

Comment: @s.d.. no error message is shown... :(

Comment: @all... thanks for your responses... glad to..
in firefox when i execute code step by step with breakpoints, the session gets logged.. but not other way... not sure of the resolution :(

Comment: <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start(); ?>  No Errors at all?

Comment: @Sbml no error msgs are seen.. not sure if am tracking it right... (am just learning php)...

Comment: hi guys... any responses to this query... still haunting me :(

Comment: Just to confirm, you haven't turned off cookies in FF and Chrome, correct?

Comment: guys i was able to fix this... it was just an issue with javascript looping.. and so wrote another logic without any looping.. that worked.. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the same page in **Incognito Window** of chrome.
PS. You can open Incognito window of chrome by pressing **Ctlr+Shift+N**..

Thanks for the hint though, Labib!